# Write address to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dereference

I have a pointer `char *a` pointing to a block of memory. I have another pointer `char *b` that points to a memory block. Let's say b points to address `0x10001111`. I want to write this address to next 8 bytes to the memory block pointed by a. In short, when I deference a, I should get the next 8 bytes of memory and value =  `0x10001111`. How do I do that? This is a x86_64 machine. 
My current code:

```
static void write_add(void *a, char *b)
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      *(unsigned long *)a= (unsigned long)b;
 *(unsigned long *)a= (unsigned long)b; 
 return;
}
```

I see only 0x00001111 on dereferencing a. Why am I not able to see the complete address?

Comment: How do you print the value? What is the size of `long` on your system? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @cad I mentioned in my question. It is a x86_64 system and I am debugging my code in gdb. It is a very small but independent fraction of the code. Thanks for helping

Comment: Ouh, yeah, overlooked that, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, only `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are guaranteed to be able to hold pointer integer values; currently, your program is implementation-defined

Comment: Since this is a nice small independent piece of code, you should be able to provide us with a nice small independent MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that shows the problem you are seeing — code and sample output.  It is not clear what you are up to yet, and therefore it is not clear what's going wrong.  What is `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(unsigned long)` on this machine/compiler?

Comment: This code may violate the strict aliasing rule, depending on how the space pointed to by `a` was allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you involve a separate, unrelated type of uncertain size?  If you want to store the pointer value in exactly 8 bytes (and supposing that the value *fits* in 8 bytes), you would spell that like so:

```
#include <stdint.h>
static void write_add(void *a, char *b) {
    *(uint64_t *) a = (uint64_t) b; 
}
```

You could also use `memcpy()`, but that seems a bit heavy-handed.

Do note, however, that C guarantees nothing about the size of the representation of pointer values.  Although it is likely that 64 bits is enough on your system, you cannot safely assume that it is enough on every system.

Comment: minor nitpick: `(uint64_t)b` would cause undefined behaviour if the pointer could not be represented in a `uint64_t`  ; using `(uintptr_t)` for the right-hand side avoids UB

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I debug on gdb, address of b = `0x400002728` but the value at a = `0x400000010:    0x00002728`. I still don't get it, why would it only copy last 4 and not full address? Sorry, if this seems naive. I am a beginner

Comment: @M.M, yes, but the answer is already expressly provisional on the converted value fitting in 8 bytes.  If it does not, then UB is moot because the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: @ShekharSharma, you are asking `gdb` the wrong question, as judged by the fact that it is printing a four-byte value for you.  (8 hexadecimal digits = 4 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long` is not necessarily 64 bits on your platform. You can't make that assumption simply because you're on a x86_64 platform. I'm willing to bet it's actually 32 bits.

You should use `uintptr_t` instead as suggested by cad. This type is always defined to be a type that is big enough to contain a pointer on your platform.